# Two local address listening on same port?

Tags: solaris, bind, netstat, port

How is it possible that `netstat -a | grep 8081` shows this:

```
localhost.8081             *.*                0      0 49152      0 LISTEN
      *.8081               *.*                0      0 49152      0 LISTEN
```

I don't really understand which means the second entry.

UPDATE_1: I've checked that two different processes are listening on 8081... I used to believe that this is not possible. One process is Jboss, which 8081 port is used to serve browser requests, and the other is Gitblit GO (It could have an embeded server in JAR), which 8081 port is used to shutdown.

Comment: if you have `lsof` installed, run `lsof -i tcp:8081` and post the output in the question.

Comment: @darcy-nader I don't have `lsof`. And my SO is Solaris.

Comment: What does `netstat -l -n` show? I'm guessing that you'll see an IPv4 and IPv6 address.

Comment: @ErikF `-l` is not a valid paramert for netstat in Solaris. However, the entries I've posted are both `TCP: IPv4 `.

Comment: It looks like one process is listening on the loopback interface, and the other is listening on, effectively, any other interface.  A client accessing localhost:8081 would connect to the first.  A client accessing <publicIP>:8081 would connect to the second.

Comment: Which version of Solaris?  If Solaris 11, you can use `netstat` directly to get the process(s) listening on a port.  On Solaris 10, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246309/how-to-get-process-id-attached-with-particular-port-in-sunos

Comment: @AndrewHenle +1 for something I'd been looking for weeks. However, how can it help me understand why two process uses same port?

Comment: @AndyDalton How can I effectively check that localhost:8081 is connected to a loopback interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following experiment to illustrate my comment above.  I use the `netcat` command to implement two simple TCP servers.  My secnario differs from yours a bit in that I explicitly bind to the public IP instead of *:8081

```
# Terminal 1
$ nc -kl 127.0.0.1 24482
```

In a separate terminal:

```
# Terminal 2
$ nc -kl <public_ip> 24482
```

From another terminal on the local host:

```
# Terminal 3
$ telnet localhost 24482
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
hi
^]
telnet> q
Connection closed.
```

After that, I see `hi` in Terminal 1.

Next, from a remote node:

```
# Terminal 4 (on remote node)
$ telnet <public_ip> 24482
Trying <public_ip>...
Connected to <public_ip>.
Escape character is '^]'.
ho
^]
telnet> q
Connection closed.
```

After that, I see `ho` in Terminal 2.

I suspect that this is the behavior that you would see, although I don't have a Solaris environment in which to test it.

Comment: Should say 'hi' in Terminal 1, right?

Comment: @abaraza Yes, I corrected the description to indicate that `hi` is seen on Terminal 1